# Creating a sequence of dates with a special format

Tags: r, regex, date, sequence

I was wondering how I could create a sequence of dates in the following format: from `"Jul 23 10:20"` to `"Jul 30 10:25"` by `"1"` day?

I tried the following without sucess:

```
seq.Date(as.Date("Jul 23 10:20"), as.Date("Jul 30 10:25"), length.out = 7)
```

Comment: Don't you want length.out=8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preserve times you should convert to actual date-times, from which it is easy to build a sequence increasing by 1 day at a time. You can use `strftime` to format this as you please.

```r
strftime(seq(as.POSIXct("2020-07-23 10:20"), by = "1 day", length.out = 7), "%b %e %H:%M")
#> [1] "Jul 23 10:20" "Jul 24 10:20" "Jul 25 10:20" "Jul 26 10:20" "Jul 27 10:20"
#> [6] "Jul 28 10:20" "Jul 29 10:20"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the dates by converting to `Date` format

```
format(seq(as.POSIXct("Jul 23 10:20", format = "%b %d %H:%M" ),
      by = "1 day", length.out = 7), "%b %d %H:%M")
#[1] "Jul 23 10:20" "Jul 24 10:20" "Jul 25 10:20" "Jul 26 10:20" "Jul 27 10:20" "Jul 28 10:20" "Jul 29 10:20"
```

---

Or with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
format(as.POSIXct("Jul 23 10:20", format = '%b %d %H:%M') + days(0:4), "%b %d %H:%M")
#[1] "Jul 23 10:20" "Jul 24 10:20" "Jul 25 10:20" "Jul 26 10:20" "Jul 27 10:20"
```

Comment: @rnorouzian sorry, I was looking at your input where there are two inputs